# Difference between using XML for static controls and making controls programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, controls

I have started using `WPF` and started with some games and visual apps.

In my first App I started a blank project then made a class that inherited from a window which had a canvas that I added and removed images from Dynamically, like follows:

```
class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Canvas canvas=new Canvas();

    public MainWindow()
    {
    this.addChild(canvas);
    }

    //add an image every second move it and remove it
}
```

This would be impossible with static **XML** but someone told me it is a bad idea to do controls dynamically, is it true?

Is it a performance loss?

And is there a simple and efficient method to draw, lets say, 100 images at a 30 fps without lag?

Comment: Let me ask you this: How can parsed text (BAML) be quicker than executable code? There's an extra step there.. so, even though the performance difference is relatively un-noticable.. there is an extra step there.

Comment: Why not use animation? You can use it in xaml, and in code behind.

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance loss / the performance loss is negligible compared to the HUGE productivity / code cleanliness gained by doing things the RIGHT way.

And XAML is not static.

There is `DataBinding`, and if you need to add / remove items dynamically there is the `ItemsControl`.

There is also the concept of `DataTemplates` that dynamically render specific UI depending on what Model / ViewModel objects are passed to it.

Do not manipulate nor create UI elements in procedural code. WPF is not winforms.

Answer (score 1):

None of the controls are really`static`. There is no any runtime difference.

Most likely, by **using XML** you meant XAML. **XAML** merely serves as a data source use to actually generate *C# code (or the code in VB.NET or other .NET language)* to compile is and to use exactly in the same was as you would do it *programmatically*.

You can use this fact in your work. If you know how to do certain things with **XAML** but don't know how to do similar thing in `C# code`, do the following: develop XAML-based project and build it. Then perform the search for `*.cs` files under the directory where your project file is located. You will find some `*.cs` files which was not in your source code. Those files were auto-generated with the use of **XAML**. Look at them.

You will be able to learn how it works behind the hood.

Good luck,

Comment: OK, i get it and I have used the `WPF` project template to see how it works. But a question about performance, will I be able to realistically display 200 image controls and update them at about 30-50 fps?